# Gallerific jQuery plugin for photo gallery - How to call the remove image function

Tags: jquery

I am using Gallerific jQuery Plugin (http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/) to show a photo gallery.

Now, I have an Delete image button. When I click on that, it calls a javascript function DeleteImage('id_2576');

Now from within this function, how can I call the Gallerific jquery function to remove an image by its hash value? I tried the following, but it does not work. No error message also is shown.

(I have initialised the 'gallery' object, and the images are displayed correctly.)

```
function DeleteImage(imageID) {
  alert("starting...";
  if (!gallery.removeImageByHash(imageID)) {
     alert('Cant remove by hash value);
 }
 else {
     alert('Removed successfully by hash value);
}
 alert('Finished...');
```

It enters the "Starting ..." alert. But it does not enter the "Finished..." alert.

Comment: Have you cut and pasted the exact code? Because you're missing a closing bracket on the first `alert` and a closing quote on the parameter for the second and third, for a start. Find some way of viewing the error console in whatever browser you're using, and find out what the exact error is. (If you tell us your browser, I'm sure we can give you some instructions.)

Comment: Part of my code is given below. The one given above was typed and thus the error. Sorry for the invonvenience.                     var ph_id = 'ph_' + photoid;
alert("Starting removal");
if (!gallery.removeImageByHash(ph_id)) {
alert('Cant remove by hash value: ' + ph_id);
}
else {
alert('Removed successfully by hash value: ' + ph_id);
}
alert("Finished removal");

Answer (score 0):

that probably means, that there is an error occuring in gallery.removeImageByHash function

get a firebug plugin and see what is the actuall error message

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your kind reply. Could you please tell me if this line of code is correct?   gallery.removeImageByHash(imageID);

Comment: Seems ok, but until you know the current error message you cannot say that this or that line of code is ok.